# Custom building of APK

Tags: android, build, build.xml

is there any way how to change, via changes in build.xml file, package name in time of build? Is it even possible?

Comment: You want to build your application via command line. isn't it?

Comment: Interesting one but why?

Comment: I want have two version of the same app, one for release and one for testing. Both should be able to run independently on one device, that's why I need to change package name